# ListView item open a new fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am making a fitness app, where I want to have 3 nesting :

1. `ListView` with muscle group items
2. `ListView` of exercises (appears when to click on item from the muscle group `ListView`)
3. and description of exercise.

[Something like this design:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqUM5.jpg)

But I don't know how do realize this.
Do I need create a new fragment to each item or I can use `ViewPager` here(if yes,how to do this)?
Give me advice,please, how to realize this design (any links of the same structure projects or any other examples)
thank you in advance

Comment: I am not sure what is I understand from the image is correct or not, are you trying to find something like this:
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

Comment: thank you for this link,but i've already seen it.
i'll expain what i want:
As I told, I am developing a fitness app
1)when start an app i shoud see a listview with  muscle groups (biceps,triceps etc.)
2)when i click on the item of this listview must open another listviews with exercises for each muscle group(depends of the items clicked)
3)then i can click on any of these listviews exercises  and some description of exercise must open

Comment: Are you meaning you will have something like:
1. ListView (Item + SubItem)
2. Every SubItem pressed will lead to a new page

Comment: No,I doesn`t want subitems.
I want listview with items. click on item - open another listview. on this listview item click - open description (text and image)
like in image I affixed

Comment: Then it is easy, just use fragment and direct the fragment switching when there is item click
 You may now have 3 fragment class, Trunk Fragment, Branch Fragment and DetailFragment
For Trunk Fragment, simply a list view and onItemClickListener to direct each item to next list (Branch Fragment)
For Branch Fragment, simply a list view and onItemClickListener to direct each item to DetailFragment

Comment: Thank you:)
maybe u have any examples?)

Comment: Ok, i may write one simple for you as example, please wait a minute

Comment: I will be very grateful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the sample code
            package com.sw.gitans201608042027;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private static MainActivity mCurrent = null;

    public static MainActivity getInstance() {
        return mCurrent;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mCurrent = this;
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        switchFragment(new ListFragment());
    }

    public void switchFragment(Fragment f) {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.container, f);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}

package com.sw.gitans201608042027;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class ListFragment extends Fragment implements OnItemClickListener {

    private String[] contents = { "a", "b" };
    private String[] aArr = { "a1", "a2" }, bArr = { "b1", "b2" };
    private SampleAdapter mAdapter;

    public ListFragment(String[] contents) {
        this.contents = contents;
    }

    public ListFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lv, container, false);
        mAdapter = new SampleAdapter(getActivity(), contents);
        ((ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.lv)).setAdapter(mAdapter);
        ((ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.lv)).setOnItemClickListener(this);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        if (mAdapter.getItem(arg2) != null) {
            if (((String) mAdapter.getItem(arg2)).equals("a") || ((String) mAdapter.getItem(arg2)).equals("b")) {
                if (((String) mAdapter.getItem(arg2)).equals("a")) {
                    if (MainActivity.getInstance() != null)
                        MainActivity.getInstance().switchFragment(new ListFragment(aArr));
                } else {
                    if (MainActivity.getInstance() != null)
                        MainActivity.getInstance().switchFragment(new ListFragment(bArr));
                }
            } else {
                if (MainActivity.getInstance() != null)
                    MainActivity.getInstance().switchFragment(new TextFragment((String) mAdapter.getItem(arg2)));
            }
        }
    }

}

package com.sw.gitans201608042027;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SampleAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private String[] contents;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public SampleAdapter(Context ctxt, String[] contents) {
        this.contents = contents;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctxt);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (contents != null)
            return contents.length;
        else
            return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        if (contents == null || position >= contents.length)
            return null;
        else
            return contents[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Holder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            holder = new Holder();
            holder.tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_txt);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
        holder.tv.setText(contents[position]);
        return convertView;
    }

    private class Holder {
        TextView tv;
    }

}

package com.sw.gitans201608042027;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TextFragment extends Fragment {

    private String desc;

    public TextFragment(String s){
        desc = s;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, container, false);
        ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.list_txt)).setText(desc);
        return v;
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
    <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.sw.gitans201608042027.MainActivity" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_txt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

lv.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: in your example you use a non-static constructor - android studio marked like a mistake.
is it good idea to use newInstance() method ?
if yes, can you explain how to make it on your code example

Comment: simply change the constructor into private and create a static method
public <Class> newInstance(Params){
 return new Class(Params);
}